# Do all API calls contain a Referer header on VodaPay Mini-Programs?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

When inspecting outbound API requests, there is a header called Referer,

In the simulator I see the referrer is https://[app-id].hybrid.alipay-eco.com/index.html where [app-id] is the App ID. I want to confirm this is the same regardless of the Sandbox environment or for Production. Also if there is any difference between simulator and device.

Comment: If you control the client, you can choose to *not* send the `Referer` header.

Comment: In this case the client isn't controlled by me, but by the framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL  https://[app-id].hybrid.alipay-eco.com is for the Referer for the simulator.

The URL  https://[app-id].sass.mini-program.com is the referrer being used in production. In both cases   is the App ID set by VodaPay.

However, if you preview the app on the device (i.e. a dev build from the simulator that is only valid for 15 min) no Referer header is sent.